# Apt update "failed to fetch" in WSL (yes me too). Connectivity ok but apt fails

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux, aptitude

Unlike for many others, it did not turn out that I have firewall software blocking me. I turned it all off. Including Windows Firewall and Windows Defender. Problem never was with connectivity. I can manually `wget` the files in question. Just `apt` fails.

```
balter@spectre:~$ sudo aptitude update
[sudo] password for balter:
Err http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve '....archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Could not resolve '....archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve '....archive.ubuntu.com'
Hit http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease: Could not resolve '....archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease: Could not resolve '....archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease: Could not resolve '....archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

balter@spectre:~$ ping archive.ubuntu.com
PING archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.161) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from keeton.canonical.com (91.189.88.161): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=149 ms
64 bytes from keeton.canonical.com (91.189.88.161): icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=152 ms
64 bytes from keeton.canonical.com (91.189.88.161): icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=152 ms
64 bytes from keeton.canonical.com (91.189.88.161): icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=243 ms
^C
--- archive.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 4 received, 20% packet loss, time 4004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 149.267/174.575/243.986/40.100 ms

balter@spectre:~$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease
--2017-11-01 22:02:21--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.88.152, 91.189.88.161, 91.189.88.162, ...
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 246846 (241K)
Saving to: ‘InRelease.1’

InRelease.1                                       100%[===========================================================================================================>] 241.06K   309KB/s    in 0.8s

2017-11-01 22:02:22 (309 KB/s) - ‘InRelease.1’ saved [246846/246846]
```

Comment: I am facing this issue in WSL 2.....did you find any fix ?